# How to input N amount of characters into string from each line of a text file?

Tags: c++, string, function

Please, if you write code in your answer, write it as if you were using namespace std;. Otherwise it's difficult for me to read :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int a; // a is amount of lines in file
string word[100];

int main()
{
    ifstream fd("file.txt");
    fd >> a;
    for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        //here goes the code which inputs, let's say, 20 first characters of a line into string array - word[i].
    }
    fd.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is `fd << a` for??

Comment: fd >> a; will show how many lines there are in text file, this way I will know how many times my for loop will need to cycle

Comment: so you store the number of lines inside the file you want to read?

Comment: Sorry for late response. In the exercises I try to solve, it's common to write  in the first line a digit which tells the amount of lines, digits or other information. Then we use that digit inside FOR loops so we knwo how many times they have to cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take into account that the file might have more than 100 lines (which would then exceed your `word`-array, and I'd also take into account that the file might be inconsistent concerning number of lines stated in `a` and actual number of lines. Given that, try the following:

```cpp
string line;
int i;
for(i=0; getline(fd, line) && i<a && i < 100; i++) {
    word[i] = line.substr(0,20);
}
// at this point, "i" will hold the number of items actually written to "word".
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I don't really care about there being more than 100 lines, because exercises are very specific and I am preparing for my programming exam (I try to solve previous years exercises). But the more you know, the better it is!